# Catch a "require()" in frontend

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, ether, require

I was trying to validate a transaction with some conditions on contract level and was wondering if it was possible in any way to give user feedback in the frontend if a require() fails - aka if it returns false.

Example

```
In contract:

function validate(x){
    require(x < y) --> outcome = false
}


In frontend: (fictional code)

try
    contract.validate(1);
catch RequireFailed
    //provide user feedback that the require failed.
```

So my question, is there any way to catch if a require fails, and if so.. How to catch it :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/how-to-catch-json-rpc-exception-in-front-end-web3/39924#39924) You can use then((result) { } )).catch(err) {}