# How to catch reverted transaction while using metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, truffle-contract, revert-opcode

I'm working with metamask and was testing a transaction that should trigger a revert statement inside my contract. When the error is thrown metamask gives the following output:
[image]
this was while using Firefox with Metamask extension installed

the following is the result of using on Chrome without the metamask extension
[image]

So as you can see i suppose the error message the extension gets its the same as the one on screenshot #2

and here is the code that produces the throw
[image]

my question is, do we have a way of catching these errors in a more 'elegant fashion' so we can know what caused the error or this the only way of catching such errors.

The approach i'm using here is similar to [How to catch JSON RPC exception in front end web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/how-to-catch-json-rpc-exception-in-front-end-web3)
EDIT:
here is my contract's code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Ive {

    address public creator;
    address public owner;


    mapping (address=>bool) allowedVisitors;
    address[] allowedVisitorsList;

    struct Client {
        address wallet;
        string apellido1;
        string apellido2;
        string apellidoCasada;
        string nombre1;
        string nombre2;
        string fechaNacimiento;
        address modifiedBy;
    }

    Client[] private clients;

    event OwnerAssigned(
        address creator,
        address owner
    );

    event VisitorAllowed(
        address owner,
        address newVisitor
    );

    event VisitorDisallowed(
        address owner,
        address newVisitor
    );

    modifier onlyAllowed() {
        if(allowedVisitors[msg.sender] == false)
            revert("Account is not allowed to obtain client info");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyCreator() {
        if(msg.sender != creator)
            revert("Only creator can execute this action");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if(msg.sender != owner)
            revert("Only owner can execute this function");
        _;
    }

    constructor () public {
        creator = msg.sender;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setClientInfo (
        string apellido1,
        string apellido2,
        string apellidoCasada,
        string nombre1,
        string nombre2,
        string fechaNacimiento
    ) 
        external returns (uint) 
    {
        Client memory newClient;

        newClient.apellido1 = apellido1;
        newClient.apellido2 = apellido2;
        newClient.apellidoCasada = apellidoCasada;
        newClient.nombre1 = nombre1;
        newClient.nombre2 = nombre2;
        newClient.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        newClient.modifiedBy = msg.sender;

        clients.push(newClient);

        return clients.length;
    }

    function getClientsLength () view public returns (uint) {
        return clients.length;
    }

    function setOwner(address _owner) onlyOwner external {
        owner = _owner;
        allowVisitor(_owner);
        // emit OwnerAssigned(msg.sender, _owner);
    }

    function obtainOwner() view external returns (address){
        return owner;
    }

    function allowVisitor(address visitor) public {
        if(!allowedVisitors[visitor]) {
            allowedVisitors[visitor] = true;
            allowedVisitorsList.push(visitor);
            emit VisitorAllowed(msg.sender, visitor);
        }
    }

    function isAllowedAccount(address account) view public returns (bool) {
        return allowedVisitors[account];
    }

    function disallowVisitor(address account) onlyOwner external {
        allowedVisitors[account] = false;
        emit VisitorDisallowed(msg.sender, account);
    }

    function getVisitorsLength() view public returns (uint) {
        return allowedVisitorsList.length;
    }

    function obtainClient(uint32 index) view onlyAllowed public returns (string, string, string, string) {
        return (clients[index].nombre1, clients[index].apellido1, clients[index].fechaNacimiento, clients[index].apellido2);
    }

    function getAllowedVisitors() view onlyOwner public returns (address[]) {
        return allowedVisitorsList;
    }

}
```

Comment: not easy to tell without the contract code

Comment: added the contract code

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood your question was actually not necessary the contact code. So far I guess that's the best way until they implement a better way as per this https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/136